# Automatically adding a user as the "assigned to" person when creating a subtask in sharepoint using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have code that currently will assign a subtask to a parent task in sharepoint. However, the challenge I'm running into is that I want, when you start to create subtasks, the subtasks are automatically assigned to the person that the parent task is assigned to.

I kinda have an idea of how to do it, using

```
oListItem.set_item('AssignedTo', "Person"
```

But I don't really know how to get the person that the parent is assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

You have a parent Task. So you can directly assign the parent Task assigned to to the sub task.

For Ex. 
Let us consider your parent Task item as "parentTaskItem".

So you can assign like

```
oListItem.set_item('AssignedTo', parentTaskItem.get_item('AssignedTo'));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm understanding it wrong? is parentTaskItem supposed to be the actual name of the parent task item?

Answer (score 0):

It need not to be.

Please check the below code.

```
    var parentItem;
function runCode() {
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
     var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');
     parentItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
     clientContext.load(parentItem, 'Title');
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');        
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);        
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'ChildTasks for Parent');
    oListItem.set_item('AssignedTo', parentItem.get_item('AssignedTo'));        
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(oListItem);        
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.ChildCreateSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));             
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function ChildCreateSuccess() {
    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}
```